# How to convert TM-2 degree coordinate to lat lon on Android?

Tags: android, gps, geocoding, coordinate-systems

I am writing a program that convert TM-2 degree to lat/lon on Android, but I can't find formula for that. I do find some example on internet, but most of them are convert with open source library, that I can't use on Android platform. I also find a java class that do convert from UTM to lat lon, but it seems no suitable for TM 2 degreen coordinate system. So my question is: how do I convert TM 2 degree coordinate to lat/lon? Where can I find formula?

Comment: What is a TM-2 degree?  Probably why you can't find anything by googling, maybe you're calling it something different?

Comment: Does TM = transverse mercator? If so, then you're asking how to convert UTM coordinates to Lat/Long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the open source libraries, and they are open source, then you can easily download the source code and take a look at the algorithm necessary for the conversion.  This is really a platform independent question, it doesn't matter much that you're on Android, once you know the algorithm you could implement it with any language you like.

Also, I don't think the official name is TM-2, I can't find references to it as a Geodetic System or as a Geographic Coordinate System.